# Data overwrite in grafana gauge

Tags: visualization, grafana, gauge, grafana-variable

I am using Grafana Dashboard to visualize the postgreSQL data.

There is dropdown list on the dashboard & data is populated on the gauge with the selection of element from dropdown list and it overwrite the previous data as shown in the image.

How can I resolve this problem ?

[image]

Comment: Can you add more details please? (Panel configurations for visualization, query etc.)

Comment: Thanks for your response. The query and panel configuration every thing is correct. Even when I load page first time on selection of element from dropdown list it show the correct one. but for second time so on it overwrite the previous data value to new one.

Comment: I see, but it’s difficult for me to help without the configuration data...